# Styling so a user sees the same exact style no matter what their user id is

Tags: php, css, styling

In my code, I have a center tag and have styled the center tag so it looks the way I want it to look. It currently looks like this:
[image: picture here]

Whenever I go on my admin account (one that has a different user id than the normal users) it looks way different than if a regular user would see it. It looks like this:
[image: picture here]

I would like to know if there is any way around this so it looks the same as if a regular would see it on an admin account.

I've tried putting a div tag around it and using the same styling features, but that didn't work. I've tried putting the center tag around different parts of the code, but since it's an "if" statement, it will look different.

Here is the code:

```
   <style>
    center{
    border-left: .17em dashed;
    border-top: .17em solid;
    border-right: .17em dashed;
        border-bottom: .17em solid;
        padding-left:25px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        width: 1000px;
        background-color: #E1A0A0;
        border-color: black;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: left;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<center><b><h2>' . $row['title'] . '</h2></b>' . $row['post'] . '<br/><br/> <b>Posted On: </b>' . $row['postdate'] . '<br/><a href="comments.php?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '">View Post Comments</a> | ';
        if($_SESSION['user_id'] == 3) {
            echo '<a href="update.php?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '" >Update Blog Post</a> | <a href="' . basename(__FILE__) . '?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '" >Delete Blog Post</a></center>';

        }
    }
    ?>
```

I know that I can't just put another center tag around the

```
"echo '<center><b><h2>' . $row['title'] . '</h2></b>' . $row['post'] . '<br/><br/> <b>Posted On: </b>' . $row['postdate'] . '<br/><a href="comments.php?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '">View Post Comments</a> |';"
```

part of the code and

```
"echo '<a href="update.php?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '" >Update Blog Post</a> | <a href="' . basename(__FILE__) . '?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '" >Delete Blog Post</a></center>';"
```

part of the code because it will look like this:
[image: picture here]

Additionally, if I put the center tag around everything, it will look like this:
[image: picture here]

I just want to make it look the same no matter who views it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the close of the `if(){}` you need to `echo '</center>'` and remove it from inside the `if(){}`. You have setup a loop where sometimes `center` is not closed

```
echo '<center><b><h2>' . $row['title'] . '</h2></b>' . $row['post'] . '<br/><br/> <b>Posted On: </b>' . $row['postdate'] . '<br/><a href="comments.php?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '">View Post Comments</a> | ';
        if($_SESSION['user_id'] == 3) {
            echo '<a href="update.php?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '" >Update Blog Post</a> | <a href="' . basename(__FILE__) . '?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '" >Delete Blog Post</a>';
        }
echo '</center>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I quite understand what is being asked for, but if all you want to do is make everything look like the last image you posted, remove this in the css:

`padding-left:25px;`

Comment: there is other code in this, and I would like it centered so it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/ndv38x . As of now, it doesn't look like that when I log into an admin account because the center is only around the first echo, not the echo that is in the 'if' statement